# Testing Java code

Tags: java, testing, cluster-computing

I have a Java program which I need to test. I have 10 datasets to work on, and need to test each dataset 25 times using 8 different algorithms for a total of 600 seconds each. If I were to test this on a single machine, it would bring the total test time to:

10*25*8*600/60/60/24 = 14 days!

Is there any other way I can do this? e.g. an online service where I can test my code simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: You can test it in parallel by using different a thread for each dataset / algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You can try spanning some Amazon EC2 instances -- they charge you by the hour per instance so if you're only going to use it for 10-15 minutes might not be too much!

Comment: ..but presumably he's going to need ~14 instance-days worth of usage.